sqlalchemy: (how) can I return a function expression from process_bind_param in a custom type?
I have a custom type for interfacing with INET6 in MariaDB, and from process_bind_param I want to return an SQL expression like this: CAST('2001::ff' AS INET6)
I've tried this so far (slightly simplified):
import ipaddress
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

class Inet6(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = types.BINARY
    cache_ok = True

    def get_col_spec(self, **kw):
        return 'INET6'

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        assert isinstance(value, ipaddress.IPv6Address)
        return cast(str(value), self)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return ipaddress.IPv6Address(value)

However, when I use it in a query, I get this exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mlenz/nnis/nnis-business-services/ip-inet6.py", line 19, in <module>
    for i in q.all():
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2693, in all
    return self._iter().all()  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2847, in _iter
    result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2308, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2190, in _execute_internal
    result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 293, in orm_execute_statement
    result = conn.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1416, in execute
    return meth(
           ^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1820, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2343, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1814, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1487, in _init_compiled
    d_param = {
              ^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1488, in <dictcomp>
    key: flattened_processors[key](compiled_params[key])
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 2059, in process
    return fixed_impl_processor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 929, in process
    return DBAPIBinary(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 128, in Binary
    return bytes(x)
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 666, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1616, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 666, in __getitem__
    return self.operate(getitem, index)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 1733, in operate
    return super().operate(op, *other, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 194, in operate
    return op_fn(self.expr, op, *other, **addtl_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 244, in _getitem_impl
    _unsupported_impl(expr, op, other, **kw)
  File "/home/mlenz/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py", line 250, in _unsupported_impl
    raise NotImplementedError(
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.NotImplementedError) Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression
[SQL: SELECT inet6_test.ip AS inet6_test_ip, inet6_test.id AS inet6_test_id, inet6_test.timestamp AS inet6_test_timestamp 
FROM inet6_test 
WHERE inet6_test.ip = %(ip_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: [{}]]

Is this (returning a CAST from process_bind_param) supported at all? Or am I just doing it wrong?
(The reason I want to produce a CAST is that because binary strings are far less readable in the emitted SQL/bind params, and for < and > comparisons, MariaDB needs explicit CAST statements when dealing string representations of IP addresses. If I simply return a binary the_ip_address.packed I get hard-to-debug errors where mariadb complains that the value isn't a valid INET6)
Update: cold it be that sqlalchemy tries to convert my CAST statement into a binary(), because the data type uses BINARY as the base type? If yes, can I tell it not to do that for bind params?
Second Update
To expand on the binary string issues, I have a table like this:
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `inet6_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` inet6 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=214872 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci

And when I run
address = IPv6Address('2001::ff')
result = session.execute(
    text('INSERT INTO inet6_test SET ip=:ip'),
    {'ip': address.packed},
)

I get
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1292, "Incorrect inet6 value: ' \\0001\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000\\0000?' for column `pop`.`inet6_test`.`ip` at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO inet6_test SET ip=%(ip)s]
[parameters: {'ip': b' \x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff'}]

but I'm pretty sure that IPv6Address.packed is the correct format, because when I run
result = session.execute(
    text('SELECT HEX(:param)'),
    {'param': address.packed},
)
for row in result:
    print(row[0])

I get back 200100000000000000000000000000FF which is correct, and SELECT CAST(X'200100000000000000000000000000FF' AS INET6) on mariadb prompt gives me 2001::ff, which shows that in general, mariadb understands the input, just not when passed through sqlalchemy.
Involved versions:

sqlalchemy==2.0.29
pymysql==1.1.0
mariadb 10.11.6


I'm on mariadb 10.11.6

Adding a user-defined type is precisely what I'm trying to do, though currently it neither works with a CAST nor with passing the IP addresses as binary to mariadb.
